How to pivot wider by group in R
This is what my data looks like:

and this is what I want it to look like

I have been trying to use pivot_wider, but since the columns I want to pivot into aren't in the data set I have been running into issues.
group_by(Person) %>% pivot_wider()

Just add in the missing data with mutate first. For example dd %>% mutate(idx=row_number(), .by=Person) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols=Person, names_from=idx, values_from=c(ID_TYPE, ID_EVENT), names_sep = "")

In the future, please do not post code or data in images. Use a  reproducible format like dput()

df %>%
   mutate(name = row_number(), .by = Person) %>%
   pivot_wider(values_from = c(ID_TYPE, ID_EVENT))

# A tibble: 2 × 7
  Person ID_TYPE_1 ID_TYPE_2 ID_TYPE_3 ID_EVENT_1 ID_EVENT_2 ID_EVENT_3
  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 1      CNS       SSTI      SSTI      N1         N2         N3        
2 2      OSTEO     OSTEO     NA        F1         F2         NA  

